# Attached properties return null

Tags: wpf, attached-properties

I have the following attached property definition:

```
public class TestFocusManager
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FocusedElementProperty =
      DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("FocusedElement", 
          typeof (UIElement), typeof(TestFocusManager));

    public static UIElement GetFocusedElement(DependencyObject obj)
    {
      return (UIElement) obj.GetValue(FocusedElementProperty);
    } 

    public static void SetFocusedElement(DependencyObject obj, UIElement value)
    {
      obj.SetValue(FocusedElementProperty, value);
    }
}
```

When I try to use it in my user control:

```
<UserControl xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             xmlns:Behaviors="clr-namespace:MyLocalProject.Behaviors" 
             Behaviors:TestFocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=testElement}"
             x:Class="LocalProject.TestView"
             x:Name="_testView">
    <TextBox x:Name="testElement" />
</UserControl>
```

The attached property always returns a null...

```
var result = TestFocusManager.GetFocusedElement(_testView); // <-- null...
var result2 = _testView.GetValue(TestFocusManager.FocusedElementProperty); // <-- again, null...
```

What am I doing wrong here?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you try to wrap `TextBox` in `StackPanel` or another container and set the `FocusedElement` property on this element?

Comment: Sorry, I can't. I need to reference the `UserControl` at a higher level later in the code, and don't have direct access to the inner elements. Unless I crawl the visual tree and test for the attached property, which I'm loathe to do...

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `GetFocusedElement` is called before the binding is actually set (you're probably calling it in the UserControl's constructor). If you call it in the `Loaded` event, it should be fine.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that then, by attaching a delegate to the `Load` event on the user control. I'll keep you posted on the results on Monday!

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and it works fine for me except you omitted the "public" keyword in your Dependency Property setter.

I'm assuming that's a typo, if not then that's you're problem.

Comment: Sorry, I had a bunch of typos in my previous post. All fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

```
local:TestFocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

you can get a reference to the user control itself and expose a public property which gives out a button. You can use this as a last resort !.

Btw whenever I have had issues with attached properties. I generally tend to put a callback or change the type to that of Object, I mean instead of UIElement tend to use object atleast I get a callback and check whats the exact type comes as a part of callback

Cheers

Comment: I don't understand how your example helps me to bind to an element *within* the `UserControl`. It looks more like your code is trying to set the focus to the `UserControl` itself, which is not what I'm trying to do...